# System V message queue sends are very slow with selinux

Tags: ipc, rhel, selinux

My System V message queue sends have slowed down significantly with selinux enabled. With selinux disabled my test program can do 1000 sends (msgsnd) in about 1,500 microseconds. With selinux enabled it takes about 25,000 microseconds to do 1,000 sends. 
Is there anything I can do to speed up this up?

```
  unsigned long long gettime()
  {
    struct timeval gtime;
    unsigned long long usecs;
    gettimeofday (&gtime,NULL);
    usecs = (((unsigned long long)gtime.tv_sec) * 1000000) + gtime.tv_usec;
    return usecs;
  }

  key_t keyval = 102715; 
  int     qid;
  if((qid = msgget( keyval, IPC_CREAT | 0660 )) == -1)
  {
    printf("msgget failed\n");
    return -1; 
  }
  printf("qid = %d\n",qid);
  struct XmitMsg 
  {
    long    mtype;     
    int     data1;
    int     data2;
  } msg;

  struct XmitMsg xmitmsg;
  xmitmsg.mtype=1;
  xmitmsg.data1=10;
  xmitmsg.data2=20;
  int length = sizeof(struct XmitMsg) - sizeof(long);        
  unsigned long long beforeTime=gettime();
  for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
  {
    int result = msgsnd( qid, &xmitmsg, length, 0);
    if (result != 0 ) printf("result=%d\n",result);
  }
  unsigned long long afterTime=gettime();
  printf("time diff=%llu\n",afterTime-beforeTime);
```